# imagemagick convert: limit trim to max X px

Tags: linux, debian, imagemagick, image-manipulation

Using ImageMagick (6.9.11-60 on debian stable), I'd like to shave off 24px left and right of an scanned page (jpg or TIFF), but only if that area would actually be "empty" (i.e. mostly white).

I'd use `-shave`, but that removes pixels even if the area isn't white.
I then thought of `-trim` but I lack the idea how to limit it to a max of 24px.

Question: How can I remove 24px left and right of a scanned image, but *only if the area is empty*?
I'm open to not using IM, it was just what first came to mind.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an ImageMagick expert, so cannot provide a one-liner, but what you
can do is run the `-trim`, then look at the result. If you output a png,
then it holds information about where the new image came from in the
original image, the *canvas* (even if it was a jpg). You can use `identify` to extract the x offset and width of the resulting image, and check if this is more than the 24 pixels you wanted trimmed. You can optionally add e.g. `-fuzz 10%` to make the trim accept more than exactly white pixels. Obviously, if you decide to do the trim, you can use `-shave` and output a jpg. Here's an example using the built-in images:

```bash
check(){
  origwidth=$(convert out.png -format "%W" info:)
  left=$(     convert out.png -format "%X" info:) 
  width=$(    convert out.png -format "%w" info:)
  let right=origwidth-left-width
  if [ "$left" -lt 24 -a "$right" -lt 24 ]
  then  echo "trim ok"
  else  echo "dont trim"
  fi
}

convert rose:    -resize 160x160 inset.jpg
convert granite: -resize 200x200 bg.jpg

composite inset.jpg -geometry +20+20 bg.jpg input.jpg
convert   input.jpg -fuzz 10% -trim         out.png
check

composite inset.jpg -geometry +30+20 bg.jpg input.jpg
convert   input.jpg -fuzz 10% -trim         out.png
check
```